# How can I subset a dataframe in a way that the rows in the new subset will have ordered numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a `df`:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(3, 2, 1))
```

I subset the `df` like so:

```
df = df[2:3, ]
```

Now, when I check `df` as follows:

```
> df

  a b
2 2 2
3 3 1
```

the first value has a number 2, and the second number has a number 3. How can I subset the original `df` in a way that the new subset will have ordered numbers?

Desired output:

```
> df

  a b
1 2 2
2 3 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the rownames to `NULL`

```
`row.names<-`(df[2:3, ], NULL)
  a b
1 2 2
2 3 1
```

---

Or change the class`to`tibble`or`data.table`which does not allow row.names i.e. it sets the row names to`NULL` by default

```
> tibble::as_tibble(df[2:3, ])
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     2
2     3     1
```